# R-How create a nested list using a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested, names

I have 2 data frames (ReportedDF, CWNIncreasedEPS). I would like to use the ith coulmn of each data frame to make a new data frame. At the end, I would like to store all these data frames in some sort of nested list. I have been able to do this on an individual basis, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it loop.

I used the following code:

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:num) {
  x <- as.data.frame(ReportedDF[,i])
  colnames(x) <- 'Est.EPS'
  y <- as.data.frame(CWNIncreasedEPS[,i])
  colnames(y) <- 'Reported.EPS'

#Add a column of dates
z <- cbind(DateDF,x,y)

l <- list(l, z)
names(l) <- tickers[i,]

}
```

And this is the beginning of the output:

```
$`DO US Equity`
$`DO US Equity`$`UA US Equity`
$`DO US Equity`$`UA US Equity`$`MSI US Equity`
$`DO US Equity`$`UA US Equity`$`MSI US Equity`$`CTXS US Equity`
$`DO US Equity`$`UA US Equity`$`MSI US Equity`$`CTXS US Equity`$`RHT US Equity`
$`DO US Equity`$`UA US Equity`$`MSI US Equity`$`CTXS US Equity`$`RHT US Equity`$`RAI US Equity`
$`DO US Equity`$`UA US Equity`$`MSI US Equity`$`CTXS US Equity`$`RHT US Equity`$`RAI US Equity`$`CELG US Equity`
list()

$`DO US Equity`$`UA US Equity`$`MSI US Equity`$`CTXS US Equity`$`RHT US Equity`$`RAI US Equity`$<NA>
        Date Est.EPS Reported.EPS
1 2015-11-30   -0.04         1.36
2 2015-12-31    0.71         1.36
3 2016-01-31    0.71         1.36
4 2016-02-29    0.71         1.37
5 2016-03-31    1.03         1.37
6 2016-04-30    1.03         1.38
7 2016-05-31    1.03         1.38
```

The numbers in my output seem to be correct, however, the list names are obviously wrong. How can I make sure each list is being named properly? (with the entry in the ith row in my data frame tickers)

DateDf looks like this (I would like to add a column of dates to each data frame):

```
   Date
1 2015-11-30
2 2015-12-31
3 2016-01-31
4 2016-02-29
5 2016-03-31
6 2016-04-30
7 2016-05-31
```

Tickers looks like this:

```
          Ticker
1 CELG US Equity
2  RAI US Equity
3  RHT US Equity
4 CTXS US Equity
5  MSI US Equity
6   UA US Equity
7   DO US Equity
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is DateDF ? What is tickers? can you proceed to a dput on these variables as well as on the two other dataframe?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I have updated the code to include what DateDF and tickers look like.

Comment: From your code, it seems that you're doing something like `setNames(Map(function(x, y) data.frame(DateDF, Est.EPS = x, Reported.EPS = y), ReportedDF, CWNIncreasedEPS), tickers[[1]])`, although your expected output is a bit confusing

Comment: @alexis_laz that is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you! (so now there is no need for a loop, correct? Is there any necessary preliminary code to this?)

Comment: @Mel : I'm not sure what you mean by preliminary -- to avoid errors or recycling rules, the "data.frame"s should have same number of rows/columns and `Ticker` should have `nrow == ncol(reportedDF)` if that's what you mean

Comment: @alexis_laz I just wasn't sure if I need code besides this, but after testing it multiple times, I realize I do not...Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @Mel to be clear, the `Map()` approach which is actually a wrapper of `mapply()` is a vectorized approach to building your list of dfs. In R, take advantage of its vectorized processes and avoid `for` looping that grows/mutates objects iteratively, reminiscent of other programming languages.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for your clarification as well!